# Curl works on CLI, but not on PHP

Tags: php, json, curl

So, I tried this cURL on CLI and it works, but not on my PHP script. 
In my PHP script, it shows `{"staff":[],"reserved":[],"types":[]}` when the json should have more specific data in it. It happens both when I used cURL and when I used `file_get_contents`.
It also doesn't work when I open it through my browser. It shows blank.

Please note: I've already created web scraper with curl on PHP hundreds of times, and usually it works great.

This is the cURL I used on CLI:

```
curl "https://foodandfarmtour.theflybook.com/api/engine/_reservations/?id=FA860873-B947-4647-BF8C-2062628E09F9&from=2015-02-01&to=2015-03-05" -H "Cookie: PHPSESSID=f1dotub17jua33qhnoat71ddc5; fbe_aid=FA860873-B947-4647-BF8C-2062628E09F9; br_dft=m"%"2Fd"%"2FY" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch" -H "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,id;q=0.6,ms;q=0.4,jv;q=0.2" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.111 Safari/537.36" -H "Accept: */*" -H "Referer: https://foodandfarmtour.theflybook.com/book/trip/fb/?id=9932552A-8FF9-4A22-827F-3AAD4F909625" -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" -H "Connection: keep-alive" --compressed -k
```

And this is the PHP script I used:

```
$id = $args[0];
$start = date('Y-m-01');
$ch = curl_init('https://foodandfarmtour.theflybook.com/api/engine/_reservations/?id='.$id.'&from='.
        $start.'&to='.date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start.' +32 days')));
var_dump('https://foodandfarmtour.theflybook.com/api/engine/_reservations/?id='.$id.'&from='.
        $start.'&to='.date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start.' +32 days')));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            "Accept: */*",
            // "Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch",
            "Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,id;q=0.6,ms;q=0.4,jv;q=0.2",
            "Connection: keep-alive",
            "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.111 Safari/537.36",
            "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest",
            "Host: foodandfarmtour.theflybook.com",
            "Referer: https://foodandfarmtour.theflybook.com/book/trip/fb/?id=9932552A-8FF9-4A22-827F-3AAD4F909625",
            "Cookie: PHPSESSID=f1dotub17jua33qhnoat71ddc5; fbe_aid=FA860873-B947-4647-BF8C-2062628E09F9; br_dft=m%2Fd%2FY"));

var_dump(curl_exec($ch));
return;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I input a wrong link to my PHP cURL scraper. It was not the same with the URL I put in the CLI. Sorry guys. Thanks for trying to answer!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using debian or ubuntu? Type this:

```
# apt-get install php5-curl
```

If you use RedHat/Fedora/CentOS you must type:

```
# yum install php-curl
```

Best regards!

Comment: No. I use Windows 7. I already install the curl for php, but thanks though :)

Comment: Take a look at xampp, wampp and another WAMP (Windows Apache2 MySQL and PHP) servers that are prepackaged and preconfigured :) https://www.apachefriends.org/es/index.html and http://www.wampserver.com/en/ for example.

Comment: Actually, I've worked with cURL PHP script a lot of time and my other scripts always work, so it's not a problem :)
I should have said it in the question. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 0):

It happens when CURL is not enabled in your web server's php.ini file.

Before using `CURL` functions in PHP Script running from web server, just validate if `CURL` extension enabled in php ini for web server.

You can check this by executing `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

Comment: Actually, I've worked with cURL PHP script a lot of time and my other scripts always work, so it's not a problem :) I should have said it in the question. I'll edit it.